# Sum Column with Oracle 11 and PHP - what's wrong?

Tags: php, database, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Trying to get a simply query going through and its not working - newbie here.

Other php files and queries do run well.

```
    $sql = "select sum(rese_nshw) as noshows from tnht_eseo where edta_data = '19.10.01'" ;

   $sumParse = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

   oci_define_by_name($sumParse, "noshows", $total);

   oci_execute($sumParse);

   while(oci_fetch($sumParse)){
       echo "noshows:". $total;
   }
```

what's wrong  ? just outputs blank.

Running the SQL query in Oracle directly, it outputs 6 as NOSHOWS for this query.

Answer (score 2):

If `EDTA_DATA` is `date` (datatype), don't compare it to a string as `'19.10.01'` *is* a string. Oracle will implicitly try to convert it to appropriate date, but that doesn't have to work always. Besides 19.10.01 can be anything (2019 Oct 01, or 19 Oct 2001, or ...), depends on NLS settings.

Take control over it; see whether using date literal helps (it always has `yyyy-mm-dd` format):

```
where edta_data = date '2019-10-01'
```

Furthermore, if `edta_data` contains time component (hours, minutes, seconds), then the simplest option is to truncate it, e.g.

```
where trunc(edta_data) = date '2019-10-01'
```

but it'll prevent Oracle from using index on that column (if it exists). It can be fixed, no problem; but - first see whether anything of above helps.

Comment: unfortunately it is as the database is setup - it does have index.

Over 183gb of data on it, so reshaping it not an option :)

Comment: however, must add - the query, when run in SQL Developer from Oracle, runs fine and as intended

Comment: @GoncaloProenca Is `edta_data` defined in the database as a `date` column or not?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson , it is defined as a DATE column.

EDTA_DATA is defined as DATE data_type, not nullable.

All the data that are entered in this column are dates in the following format : yy-mm-dd , ie, 19.10.01, 19.10.02, etc.

If I run the SQL on SQL Developer , it works flawlessly.

I changed to python ( because at least Oracle does give me some feedback on what's wrong ) and : 

`cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from TNHT_ESEO where EDTA_DATA = '19.01.01'" )
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01843: not a valid month`

Comment: using your ideias :

Comment: `cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from TNHT_ESEO where EDTA_DATA = date '2019.01.01'" )
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

 cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from TNHT_ESEO where EDTA_DATA = date '19.01.01'" )
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
`

Comment: `cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from TNHT_ESEO where trunc(EDTA_DATA) = date '19.01.01'" )
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

  cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from TNHT_ESEO where trunc(EDTA_DATA) = date '2019.01.01'" )
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`

Comment: so im lost :) ideas ?

Comment: Sure. Date literal must be in format `yyyy-mm-dd`, not *any* format. So: `where edta_data = date '2019-01-01'`.

Comment: @GoncaloProenca the dates in a DATE column are not in any format, it’s binary data. You need to compare it with a DATE value, not a string like `'19.01.01'`. It only works in SQL Developer due to some default conversion settings in the app. The Python environment doesn’t have those defaults, and you should not rely on default conversion settings anyway.

Comment: @GoncaloProenca the syntax for DATE literals is here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Upper Case as defined here:

> column_name The column name used in the query.
>
> Use uppercase for Oracle's default, non-case sensitive column names.
>   Use the exact column name case for case-sensitive column names.

from: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-define-by-name.php

Then:
oci_define_by_name($sumParse, "NOSHOWS", $total);

Comment: Not working :(

Modified the code as you said, still returns blank.

`$sql = "select sum(RESE_NSHW) as noshows from TNHT_ESEO where EDTA_DATA = '19.10.01'" ;

   $sumParse = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

   oci_define_by_name($sumParse, "NOWSHOWS", $total);

   oci_execute($sumParse);

   while(oci_fetch($sumParse)){
       echo "noshows: ". $total;
   }`

If I run the query in Oracles SQL Developer, returns NOSHOWS column with result 6

Comment: Hmmm in your code for the line i said you are using: 'oci_define_by_name($sumParse, "NOWSHOWS", $total);'
but it is
'oci_define_by_name($sumParse, "NOSHOWS", $total);'